# How to pass searched value from one php file to another

Tags: php

Im trying to pass a searched value which in searchschoolsthis.php to excel.php. When I click 'Cetak', it generate the excel file but without the searched data. I tried checking that excel.php by putting this:

```
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM schools WHERE kod_sekolah='Q'";
```

It prints the data I wanted which is any data kod_sekolah that contains 'Q'. This means that the excel.php is working. But how can I pass the data which is entered and searched in searchschools.php to excel.php by clicking 'Cetak'?

searchschoolsthis.php

```
 <body>



<form method="post" action="searchschoolsthis.php">
<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true" />

<label><span class="style2">Pilih Kategori:</span>
<span class="style1">
<select name="category">
  <option value="negeri">NEGERI</option>
  <option value="daerah">DAERAH</option>
  <option value="kod_sekolah">KOD SEKOLAH</option>
</select>
 </span></label>

 <span class="style1">
 <span class="style2">Taip Kriteria
 <label>:</label>
 </span>
 <label>
 <input type="text" name="criteria" onKeyUp="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();"/>
 </label>
 <input type="submit" value="Cari" />
            </form>  


                            <form action="excel.php" method="post" name="criteria" target="_blank" id="cetak">
            <input type="submit" name="cetak" id="cetak" value="Cetak" />

             </form>


 </span>


   <table width='100%' color='black' id='header'>

   <thead>
    <tr>
      <td width="40%" scope="col"><div align="center"><span class="style2">Kod Sekolah</span></div></td>
      <td width="40%" scope="col"><div align="center"><span class="style2">Nama Sekolah</span></div></td>
      <td width="40%" scope="col"><div align="center"><span class="style2">PTJ</span></div></td>
      <td width="40%" scope="col"><div align="center"><span class="style2">Server</span></div></td>
      <td width="40%" scope="col"><div align="center"><span class="style2">PC</span></div></td>
      <td width="40%" scope="col"><div align="center"><span class="style2">NB</span></div></td>
      <td width="40%" scope="col"><div align="center"><span class="style2">Mono Laser</span></div></td>
      <td width="40%" scope="col"><div align="center"><span class="style2">Color Laser</span></div></td>
      <td width="40%" scope="col"><div align="center"><span class="style2">Dot Matrix</span></div></td>
      <td width="40%" scope="col"><div align="center"><span class="style2">LCD</span></div></td>
      <td width="40%" scope="col"><div align="center"><span class="style2">Set LAN</span></div></td>
      <td width="40%" scope="col"><div align="center"><span class="style2">Jumlah Kos</span></div></td>
      <td width="40%" scope="col"><div align="center"><span class="style2">Dibayar</span></div></td>
      <td width="50%" scope="col"><div align="center"><span class="style2">Tanggungan</span></div></td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
    </table>


<?php

    if(isset($_POST['submitted'])){

    include('connect.php');
    $category=$_POST['category'];
    $criteria=$_POST['criteria'];
    $query="SELECT * FROM schools WHERE $category = '$criteria'";
    $result=mysqli_query($dbcon,$query) or die('error getting data');


    echo "<table width='120%' border='2' color='black' id='header'>";


    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)){


    echo"<tr><td>";

    echo $row['kod_sekolah'];

    echo"</td><td>";       

    echo $row['nama_sekolah'];
    echo"</td><td>";

    echo $row['ptj'];
    echo"</td><td>";

    echo $row['server'];
    echo"</td><td>";

    echo $row['pc'];
    echo"</td><td>";

    echo $row['nb'];
    echo"</td><td>";

    echo $row['mono_laser'];
    echo"</td><td>";

    echo $row['color_laser'];
    echo"</td><td>";

    echo $row['dot_matrix'];
    echo"</td><td>";

    echo $row['lcd'];
    echo"</td><td>";

    echo $row['set_lan'];
    echo"</td><td>";

    echo $row['jumlah_kos'];
    echo"</td><td>";

    echo $row['dibayar'];
    echo"</td><td>";

    echo $row['tanggungan'];
    //echo"</td><td  style='text-align:right'>";

    echo"</td></tr>";

    }

    echo "</table>";

    }


    ?>
    </body>
```

excel.php

```
    <body>
<?


   include("connect.php");
            $objDB = mysqli_select_db($dbcon,$strSQL);

            $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM schools WHERE kod_sekolah='Q'";
            //$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM schools WHERE negeri== '$criteria'";
            $objQuery = mysqli_query($dbcon,$strSQL);
            if($objQuery)
            {                      

                    $strPath = realpath(basename(getenv($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"])));


                    $strFileName = "Excel.xls";


                    $xlApp = new COM("Excel.Application");
                    $xlBook = $xlApp->Workbooks->Add();



                    $xlBook->Worksheets(1)->Name = "Rekod";                                                
                    $xlBook->Worksheets(1)->Select;


                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Range("A1:A1")->ColumnWidth = 10.0;
                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Range("B1:B1")->ColumnWidth = 13.0;
                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Range("C1:C1")->ColumnWidth = 23.0;
                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Range("D1:D1")->ColumnWidth = 12.0;
                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Range("E1:E1")->ColumnWidth = 13.0;
                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Range("F1:F1")->ColumnWidth = 12.0;


                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Range("A1:F1")->BORDERS->Weight = 1;
                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Range("A1:F1")->MergeCells = True;
                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Range("A1:F1")->Font->Bold = True;
                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Range("A1:F1")->Font->Size = 20;
                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Range("A1:F1")->HorizontalAlignment = -4108;                              
                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells(1,1)->Value = "Rekod Penyelenggaraan ICT di Sekolah-Sekolah";


                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells(3,1)->Value = "Kod Sekolah";
                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells(3,1)->Font->Bold = True;
                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells(3,1)->VerticalAlignment = -4108;
                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells(3,1)->HorizontalAlignment = -4108;
                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells(3,1)->BORDERS->Weight = 1;

                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells(3,2)->Value = "Nama Sekolah";
                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells(3,2)->Font->Bold = True;
                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells(3,2)->VerticalAlignment = -4108;
                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells(3,2)->HorizontalAlignment = -4108;
                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells(3,2)->BORDERS->Weight = 1;

                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells(3,3)->Value = "PTJ";
                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells(3,3)->Font->Bold = True;
                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells(3,3)->VerticalAlignment = -4108;
                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells(3,3)->HorizontalAlignment = -4108;
                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells(3,3)->BORDERS->Weight = 1;

                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells(3,4)->Value = "Server";
                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells(3,4)->Font->Bold = True;
                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells(3,4)->VerticalAlignment = -4108;
                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells(3,4)->HorizontalAlignment = -4108;
                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells(3,4)->BORDERS->Weight = 1;

                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells(3,5)->Value = "PC";
                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells(3,5)->Font->Bold = True;
                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells(3,5)->VerticalAlignment = -4108;
                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells(3,5)->HorizontalAlignment = -4108;
                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells(3,5)->BORDERS->Weight = 1;

                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells(3,6)->Value = "NB";
                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells(3,6)->Font->Bold = True;
                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells(3,6)->VerticalAlignment = -4108;
                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells(3,6)->HorizontalAlignment = -4108;
                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells(3,6)->BORDERS->Weight = 1;

                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells(3,7)->Value = "Mono Laser";
                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells(3,7)->Font->Bold = True;
                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells(3,7)->VerticalAlignment = -4108;
                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells(3,7)->HorizontalAlignment = -4108;
                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells(3,7)->BORDERS->Weight = 1;

                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells(3,8)->Value = "Color Laser";
                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells(3,8)->Font->Bold = True;
                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells(3,8)->VerticalAlignment = -4108;
                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells(3,8)->HorizontalAlignment = -4108;
                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells(3,8)->BORDERS->Weight = 1;

                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells(3,9)->Value = "Dot Matrix";
                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells(3,9)->Font->Bold = True;
                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells(3,9)->VerticalAlignment = -4108;
                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells(3,9)->HorizontalAlignment = -4108;
                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells(3,9)->BORDERS->Weight = 1;

                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells(3,10)->Value = "LCD";
                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells(3,10)->Font->Bold = True;
                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells(3,10)->VerticalAlignment = -4108;
                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells(3,10)->HorizontalAlignment = -4108;
                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells(3,10)->BORDERS->Weight = 1;

                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells(3,11)->Value = "Set LAN";
                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells(3,11)->Font->Bold = True;
                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells(3,11)->VerticalAlignment = -4108;
                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells(3,11)->HorizontalAlignment = -4108;
                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells(3,11)->BORDERS->Weight = 1;

                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells(3,12)->Value = "Jumlah Kos";
                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells(3,12)->Font->Bold = True;
                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells(3,12)->VerticalAlignment = -4108;
                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells(3,12)->HorizontalAlignment = -4108;
                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells(3,12)->BORDERS->Weight = 1;

                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells(3,13)->Value = "Dibayar";
                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells(3,13)->Font->Bold = True;
                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells(3,13)->VerticalAlignment = -4108;
                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells(3,13)->HorizontalAlignment = -4108;
                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells(3,13)->BORDERS->Weight = 1;

                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells(3,14)->Value = "Tanggungan";
                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells(3,14)->Font->Bold = True;
                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells(3,14)->VerticalAlignment = -4108;
                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells(3,14)->HorizontalAlignment = -4108;
                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells(3,14)->BORDERS->Weight = 1;



                    $intRows = 4;
                    while($objResult = mysqli_fetch_array($objQuery))
                    {


                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells($intRows,1)->Value = $objResult["kod_sekolah"];
                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells($intRows,1)->BORDERS->Weight = 1;
                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells($intRows,1)->HorizontalAlignment = -4108;

                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells($intRows,2)->Value = $objResult["nama_sekolah"];
                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells($intRows,2)->BORDERS->Weight = 1;

                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells($intRows,3)->Value = $objResult["ptj"];
                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells($intRows,3)->BORDERS->Weight = 1;

                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells($intRows,4)->Value = $objResult["server"];
                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells($intRows,4)->HorizontalAlignment = -4108;
                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells($intRows,4)->BORDERS->Weight = 1;

                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells($intRows,5)->Value = $objResult["pc"];
                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells($intRows,5)->BORDERS->Weight = 1;
                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells($intRows,5)->HorizontalAlignment = -4108;

                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells($intRows,6)->Value = $objResult["nb"];
                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells($intRows,6)->BORDERS->Weight = 1;

                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells($intRows,7)->Value = $objResult["mono_laser"];
                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells($intRows,7)->BORDERS->Weight = 1;

                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells($intRows,8)->Value = $objResult["color_laser"];
                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells($intRows,8)->BORDERS->Weight = 1;

                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells($intRows,9)->Value = $objResult["dot_matrix"];
                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells($intRows,9)->BORDERS->Weight = 1;

                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells($intRows,10)->Value = $objResult["lcd"];
                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells($intRows,10)->BORDERS->Weight = 1;

                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells($intRows,11)->Value = $objResult["set_lan"];
                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells($intRows,11)->BORDERS->Weight = 1;

                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells($intRows,12)->Value = $objResult["jumlah_kos"];
                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells($intRows,12)->BORDERS->Weight = 1;

                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells($intRows,13)->Value = $objResult["dibayar"];
                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells($intRows,13)->BORDERS->Weight = 1;

                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells($intRows,14)->Value = $objResult["tanggungan"];
                    $xlApp->ActiveSheet->Cells($intRows,14)->BORDERS->Weight = 1;

                    $intRows++;
                    }                              

                    @unlink($strFileName);  

                    $xlBook->SaveAs($strPath."/".$strFileName);



                    $xlApp->Application->Quit();
                    $xlApp = null;
                    $xlBook = null;
                    $xlSheet1 = null;

            }



?>
Fail Excel Telah Berjaya Dijana. <a href="<?=$strFileName?>">Klik Disini</a> Untuk Muat Turun.
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say that just change

```
<form action="excel.php" method="post" name="criteria" target="_blank" id="cetak">
   <input type="submit" name="cetak" id="cetak" value="Cetak" />
</form>
```

to

```
<form action="excel.php?criteria=<?php echo url_encode($_POST['criteria']); ?>" method="post" name="criteria" target="_blank" id="cetak">
   <input type="submit" name="cetak" id="cetak" value="Cetak" />
</form>
```

and change:

```
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM schools WHERE kod_sekolah='Q'";
```

to:

```
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM schools WHERE kod_sekolah='" . $_GET['criteria'] . "'";
```

PS: This is just a basic code u need to protect it against SQL Injection etc. etc.
PPS: There is more than one way to skin this cat. This is just one way.

Comment: I just wanted to downvote your answer because of SQL Injection vulnerability, but since you warned about that, I will not do this. I will not upvote you either, because you did not say how exactly prevent SQL Injection and someone may end up using your solution without SQL Injection prevention...

Comment: I just focused on the problem on hand I was not aiming for a HARDENED enterprise solution. But thanks I guess.

Comment: This is really not "_hardened enterprise solution_", this is rather "_common practice for sites accessible publicly_" (and even non-public ones). I do not know about you, but I would be really concerned with my _personal_ data being leaked (even though there is nothing that is really secret). Anyways, using SQL Injection prevention is rather simple, yet very important thing no developer should avoid. It is a standard that PHP frameworks enable such prevention by default, when their query builders are used. To sum up: do not underestimate SQL injection.

Comment: I totally agree with you on that, I never said that it is not important but rather I said that here I focused on the PROBLEM at HAND rather than giving out a FINISHED product. Here,  I the steps needed for SQL injection + URL injection + CSRF etc. etc. because that would have actually buried the actual problem. My intention was to give an idea on how to do things rather than spoon feeding.

Comment: I tried doing the changes that you mentioned and now I got this error on searchschoolsthis.php "Fatal error: Call to undefined function url_encode() in C:\xampp\htdocs....\searchschoolsthis.php on line 213"

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
<form action="excel.php" method="post" name="criteria" target="_blank" id="cetak">
    <input type="submit" name="cetak" id="cetak" value="Cetak" />
    <input type="hidden" name="criteria" value="<?= isset($_POST['criteria']) ? $_POST['criteria'] : '' ?>" />
</form>
```

Comment: I tried to do the changes that you mentioned and it generate the excel file but without the searched data. :(